# Bootstrap javascript not working after including app.js Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I've included laravel app.js in order to use Vue but now my Twitter Bootstrap dropdowns are not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/app.js') !!}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js') !!}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js') !!}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/js/plugins/loaders/pace.min.js') !!}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/js/plugins/loaders/blockui.min.js') !!}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/js/plugins/ui/nicescroll.min.js') !!}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/js/plugins/ui/drilldown.js') !!}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/js/core/app.js') !!}"></script>
```

As soon as I remove the first script (Laravel's app.js) dropdowns are working fine again.

Comment: your question is not quite clear. are you using bootstrap for dropdown or you're using vue to populate dropdown?

Comment: @imrealashu I'm using bootstrap for dropdown. Now I want to use Vue to create component not related in any way to dropdown but as soon as I included app.js bootstrap's dropdowns stopped working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel's default npm package already includes Twitter Bootstrap javascript. Now you're executing the same code twice, which may cause errors and break your dropdown, but also all other javascript on your page.

Comment: You'r right ! After removing `<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js') !!}"></script>` it works fine. Thanks !

Comment: For other that want to remove Laravel's included boostrap there is line in boostrap.js (not related to Twitter boostrap) that requires it

Comment: you are my hero